# How true is it that people vote for parties/people that benefit their stances most? Then does majority rule offer "best outcomes"?

Tags: democracy, political-theory

How true is it that people vote for parties/people that benefit their stances most?

Because if it's true, then it leads to speculation as to, whether voting in democracies is "weighted" enough. Since e.g., if there are *more people* voting for, say, economic inequality than against economic inequality, then economic inequality would get more power (by majority rule), regardless of whether it's what really should get most power.

Then, if the voting system is stupid enough, it would be possible to legally claim that "hey, we have a majority vote here". But, if the majority idea is not, what should be chosen, then what rules does a democracy have against "false majority"? That's a majority rule that seems like a majority rule (since it has more votes), but which in which case the thing being implemented is not very sane.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what that last paragraph of yours is supposed to mean.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. However you should edit this to make the question clear. Read carefully what you have written to check that it makes sense and helps the reader to understand the question.

Comment: This is one possible interpretation out of many. However because the underlying issues are so complex, information is sparse and time spent researching politics is limited, people don't know for sure if they actually benefit beforehand, making this somewhat irrelevant

Comment: @Raditz_35 What you mean "irrelevant"? I think politics has wrong methodology, if politicians think that if they only get majority vote, then that's enough to say that "this policy is true". That's a very naive and arbitrary view on reality then. Still these rules are made to apply to everyone in a society.

Comment: @mavavilj I think you are confusing how they sell their politics with how they make them. I would argue few democratically elected leaders believe that whatever they do is "true"

Comment: @Raditz_35 Have you heard about cognitive biases? I would argue that it's likely that what they do believe is that they're "doing the correct thing". But that's because they (as many of us and in some cases at least) are unable to perceive faults, because of cognitive biases.

Comment: @mavavilj That's a very simplified picture of politics. Usually it's not one person making decisions but a process. Negotiations with many interested parties, finding a solution that makes several people happy and then selling it to the public. It might seem like they are a bunch of people sitting in a dark room hatching evil plans, but usually they are not. Politicians are just really good at selling their policies and saying "I'm democratically elected so I'm doing what the people want" is just too nice of an argument to not use

Comment: @Raditz_35 Judging by the failure of many policies being implemented in the 20th century, politics has not much developed from propaganda and personal beliefs/opinions. The war against drugs for example is based on false beliefs, not science. Still it's what people get. So those kinds of policies are just simply unscientific. I would not hesitate to think that politics involves a lot of "desires of WANTING MY rule to apply and not YOUR rule" and much less of actually looking at data, which is a skill of its own. Many politicians aren't experts in science.

Comment: If you think that if politicians would just use science, everything would be fine, you don't know science.

Comment: @Raditz_35 I think empirics and statistics nearly always trump personal, subjective beliefs. However, in practice, they are usually used in conjunction. However, also in practice, I believe that politics may refuse to rely on statistical truth. That's how it's in war against drugs. Statistics say that war against drugs does not work and is targeted towards a small minority at the cost of a majority.

Comment: All you are saying basically is that if you knew beforehand what  option would give you the desired outcome, one should select said option. Sounds great, I would vote for a politician that knows the future, well, if I agree with them

Comment: @Raditz_35 But that's how politicians do it in cases like war against drugs. They don't know what will happen. However, since it has been running for 100 years or so soon, then there's now enough data to curb it as a failure. Still some refuse to do so. There are still political parties wanting to continue the ban on drugs using the same false argumentation as nearly 100 years ago. I believe that it doesn't even take this long to realize whether a policy works or not. 1 or 2 years of "test application" could be enough.

Comment: This is sort of what I'm asking in this question as well. It's possible that the majority belief is false.

Comment: I read an article once that made a convincing argument that people vote for their beliefs more often than they vote for their personal benefit.

Comment: @userLTK I'd expect correlation between personal benefit and personal belief. How else would one be right-wing and want to uphold economic inequality?

Comment: The answer to your question is "human nature". And before someone discusses how that is bad and should be fixed, there is an evolutionary benefit to voting with your gut vs voting with your brain.  That is being part of the mob is safer than being the individual that just wants the truth and justice. History has proven this many times: Hitler's rise, LA Riots, Communism: the biggest best intention that goes wrong in the face of human nature

Comment: "benefit their stances most" - you need to start with the fact that most for issues, even answering that question is at best very difficult and at works objectively impossible. Most answers will be purely ideologically based, and not reflect accurate projections of first, second, and third order effects of impacts of the policy proposed.

Comment: "Should" is a red flag of an opinion.

Comment: "But, if the majority idea is not, what should be chosen, then what rules does a democracy have against "false majority"?" - who decides what "should" be chosen?  You?  Me? An elite squad of dedicated detectives who investigate vicious felonies known as the Special Victims Unit?

Answer (score 5):

Most democracies, and certainly all democratic countries implement "representative democracy" to some degree. (Someone will mention Switzerland, but it too is far from a direct democracy.)

In a representative democracy, instead of the electorate deciding on issues, the electorate chooses representatives, who then decide on particular issues. This separation between voters and legislation allows for representatives to consider what is right as well as what is popular.

For example in 1965, the UK government decided to abolish the death penalty for murder, even though opinion polls showed that a majority of people supported the death penalty until about 2015.

A representative is not a delegate. He or she is not directed by the electorate on how to vote. They can and do use their judgement, and sometimes (as in the example of capital punishment) are able to take decisions that are directly in opposition to the will of the majority.

Answer (score 4):

TLDR:
Voters have a rational disincentive to hold their legislators and politicians accountable; politicians react to voter ignorance by being captured by special interests when "the public good" is broadly and not narrowly defined; bureaucracies become self-serving; all of which promotes government failure.  However all that being said, democratic countries tend to produce better outcomes for their constituents that autocratic regimes.

According to Public Choice Theory:

Most people have a rational disincentive to be [informed on the subjects](http://www.econlib.org/library/Enc1/PublicChoiceTheory.html).

> One of the chief underpinnings of public choice theory is the lack of incentives for voters to monitor government effectively. Anthony Downs, in one of the earliest public choice books, An Economic Theory of Democracy, pointed out that the voter is largely ignorant of political issues and that this ignorance is rational. Even though the result of an election may be very important, an individual's vote rarely decides an election. Thus, the direct impact of casting a well-informed vote is almost nil; the voter has virtually no chance to determine the outcome of the election. So spending time following the issues is not personally worthwhile for the voter. Evidence for this claim is found in the fact that public opinion polls consistently find that less than half of all voting-age Americans can name their own congressional representative.

Public Choice theory further postulates on the nature of politicians, even if the public good could be defined in a pluralistic society (same source):

> Public choice economists also examine the actions of legislators. Although legislators are expected to pursue the "public interest," they make decisions on how to use other people's resources, not their own. Furthermore, these resources must be provided by taxpayers and by those hurt by regulations whether they want to provide them or not. Politicians may intend to spend taxpayer money wisely. Efficient decisions, however, will neither save their own money nor give them any proportion of the wealth they save for citizens. There is no direct reward for fighting powerful interest groups in order to confer benefits on a public that is not even aware of the benefits or of who conferred them. Thus, the incentives for good management in the public interest are weak. In contrast, interest groups are organized by people with very strong gains to be made from governmental action. They provide politicians with campaign funds and campaign workers. In return they receive at least the "ear" of the politician and often gain support for their goals.
>
> In other words, because legislators have the power to tax and to extract resources in other coercive ways, and because voters monitor their behavior poorly, legislators behave in ways that are costly to citizens.

These two conditions, tied to bureaucratic self-dealings and interest (in the Weber definition of the life-cycle of bureaucracies) leads directly to government failures:

> But public choice economists point out that there also is such a thing as "government failure." That is, there are reasons why government intervention does not achieve the desired effect. ...Congress has frequently passed laws that are supposed to protect people against environmental pollution. But Robert Crandall has shown that congressional representatives from northern industrial states used the 1977 Clean Air Act amendments to reduce competition by curbing economic growth in the Sunbelt. The amendments required tighter emissions standards in undeveloped areas than in the more developed and more polluted areas, which tend to be in the East and Midwest.

However, all that being said, democracies do tend to produce better security, both financial and physical outcomes, for their constituents, and are more vibrant technologically and intellectually, than autocratic regimes, a theme that William McNeill demonstrably proves in the [Pursuit of Power](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0226561585)

Comment: Is there a proof for "democracies do tend to produce better security, both financial and physical outcomes, for their constituents, and are more vibrant technologically and intellectually, than autocratic regimes"?

Comment: @mavavilj  Yes, but it's a deeper discussion as indicated by me posting a book for reference, and probably not suited for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Winston S. Churchill — "Democracy is the worst form of government, except for all the others."

It's the best form of government we have compared to the rest just look at the remaining monarchies, religious oligarchies and one party States that work hard to oppress journalistic and expressive freedom and change in their countries.

Voters should vote in their own self-interest. Unfortunately unscrupulous politicians will try to use this against them.

Jack Lang - "Always back the horse named self-interest, son. It'll be the only one trying"

Answer (score 0):

A few points about difficulties with your subquestion 2:

- Others have already pointed out that there's the difficulty to decide whose vote should be upweighted (i.e. who decides what is right).
  IMHO, you'd need to prove that your proposed weighing scheme is better than the one we have. In political terms, you need to convince.
  But not knowing any weighing scheme that clearly superior, we refrain from weighting them.
- In addition you need to consider that there are be lots of questions in politics that may have - even objectively(!) - no single right answer.
  Two books I read that have influenced my world-view in this direction are [Sedlaček's Economy of Good and Evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom%C3%A1%C5%A1_Sedl%C3%A1%C4%8Dek_(economist)#Economics_of_Good_and_Evil) that describes economic world-views as political and cultural positions rather than absolute truths. 
  and the studies described in [Poor Economics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poor_Economics) that often compared possible lines of action that were plausible from a "capitalistic"/right vs. "socialistic"/left world-view. They did *not* find that the capitalistic or the socialistic world-view is right in the sense that the corresponding proposals would generally work and the other wouldn't. There was no such clear winner, even if the individual studies found what worked in the question at hand and what didn't.
  Personally, I decided to treat economic politics like religion: everyone should be entitled to their own belief. And I think these questions are purely political in the sense that a society may need to take some decision on how they organize themselves, but I do expect that e.g. several ways of organizing a society would be viable.
- Constitutions are used to give guidance and limits to what simple majorities can decide, and are intentionally set up in a way that makes them harder to change (e.g. changes requiring substantially higher majorities than simple 50% majority, and possibly lengthy procedures).
- If you have a rule of law in addition to democracy, jurisdiction/courts are there to balance legisalative and executive power and again limit the power your "false" majority has.

Answer (score -3):

#### "Democracy is two wolves and a lamb voting on what to have for lunch"

In a modern society it is considered almost blasphemous to criticize democracy and to propose alternative solutions. Adjective "undemocratic" is so powerful that it even allows military intervention (Iraq, Libya etc ...) .

In reality, [flaws of democracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plato%27s_five_regimes#Democracy) were already pointed out by Plato more then 2000 years ago. And that was before universal suffrage which gave right to vote to any fool turned 18 or 21.

Since people, especially in our egoistic time, tend to vote **primarily on perception of their own interest**, it is enough to persuade them that robbing their neighbor is in their best interest, and you would get self-destructive movements. Typical example is [persecution of White farmers in Zimbabwe](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/africa/zimbabwe-seized-white-farmers-land-now-some-are-being-invited-back/2015/09/14/456f66d6-45d2-11e5-9f53-d1e3ddfd0cda_story.html?noredirect=on&utm_term=.782e880b4ff3), which included rape and murder as tactics, only to create dire economic crisis. Similar, only not so severe outcome, happens now in [SAR](https://www.news.com.au/finance/economy/world-economy/south-africa-farm-attacks-brutal-crimes-landowners-face/news-story/dfaabafca743056b6d6656ea1fff49eb).

Problem how to replace current democracy is not easy to solve. First, it would require elimination of special interest like mass media and those who control it, and second it would have to abolish right to vote to those who are not interested in common good. There were propositions to allow voting only to those who have certain IQ level, certain education and who have done **some form of national service**. But this is a broad topic and warants its own question.

Comment: Yeah I feel like democracy is held as a too "sacred" thing. And there's a belief that democracy really means "you get what you want", even though I find that representative democracy is just a lighter form of authoritarianism. It's better than monarchy, but still not very democractic.

Comment: @mavavilj Representative democracy is actually just a particracy. You don't have much of chance to be elected if you do not have party support and/or huge sums of money for campaign. Especially if you are not already well known.

Comment: Interesting. I've been fed the perception that democracy = good. Just after I read anarchist philosophies I came to understand that the things that a minority of politicians hold as beliefs are very debatable. And noticed that politicians are not usually very experts at anything.

Comment: @mavavilj Humans as a specie are genetically hard-coded to be social animals. 90+ % of humans are not leaders, they are followers. Therefore, they instinctively seek strong figure that seems to represent their perceived interests, instead of seeking solution by themselves. And that is why we have professional political class.

Comment: @mavavilj Democracy is not "good", the quote in Stevernator's answer is very accurate. It's a bad system, but all other systems have produced even worse outcomes. Until a radically new form of government appears, we're either stuck with an imperfect democracy or something worse.

Comment: @rs.29 Preventing people without a certain IQ or education from voting is a meritocracy, which has all new problems. For example, who has the power to decide what merits access to the vote? Who designs the IQ tests and selects the teachers that provide the education? It's very easy to design tests to exclude people you don't like and to introduce bias into the classroom to make sure that those that were educated have opinions beneficial to you. If those that make those decisions are not truly neutral - and no one is truly neutral - then it quickly devolves into an autocracy.

Comment: @SCMorfildur IQ tests are already standardized, and so is education in most countries. Disagreeing does not have anything to do with it, you could disagree with theory of evolution, it is important that you know about it.

Comment: @rs.29 But I think IQ tests are lousy indicators of "general performance". Because they are short-term tests. Whereas a lot of smart human action is about thinking in the long-term. Ethics and stuff, IQ tests don't inform about those. A better test would be something that tries to gauge the "goodness" of a person. But value systems are difficult to argue as non-subjective.

Comment: Democracy as a bad thing is written all over the United States Constitution which took great pains to protect the rights of the minority (using the broadest sense... 3/5ths Compromise and all that) from tyranny of the majority.  In fact President Lincoln used the word democracy as a pejorative.

Comment: @mavavilj IQ tests measure intelligence, and people with higher intelligence tend to think more about future then people with lower intelligence who seek instant gratification. IQ tests of course do not measure ethics, that is way I proposed some kind of national service as prerequisite for voting. It would weed out at least some of irresponsible and egoistic.

Comment: @hszmv That is true, US was designed as a Republic, but slowly slided into democracy with universal suffrage .

Comment: @rs.29:  Depends on what you mean by "Republic".  A Republic is just a government in which the people control the government (or a government without a Monarch).  In the U.S. Republic is frequently used to mean Representative Democracy, which the country always has been.

Comment: @hszmv Republic is res publica, or public thing, public good or public affair. Meaning that state affairs are affairs of those who are interested and knowledgeable in state affairs, not monarchs or uneducated rabble (demos) who does not care about public good.